# Helm override values.yaml with set in array

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, helm3

I have seen many questions surrounding this topic but no good answer for what I am seeing. We have a values file like so:

```
ingress:
  enabled: "false"
  className: ""
  annotations:
    {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

We want to override the value of the list item "host". It was my expectation that `--set ingress.hosts[0].host="www.myhost.com"` would do this, but we are seeing an error stating `no matches found: ingress.hosts[0].host=www.myhost.com`.

What am I missing? This is Helm 3.9.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets in `Zsh` have special meanings, so if you use `Zsh` (based on your error, I think it's the case), you need just to escape them by putting `\` (backslash) before them:

```
--set ingress.hosts\[0\].host="www.myhost.com"
```

or by adding `noglob` before your command:

```
noglob helm ...
```

You can also escape them by default by adding this alias to your `.zshrc`:

```
alias helm='noglob helm'
```

Comment: A slightly more succinct way would be to just quote the argument: `--set 'ingress.hosts[0].host="www.myhost.com"'`

Comment: All three of these workarounds worked, thanks to the both of you! As you can probably guess I am a Mac user, maybe it is time to revert to `Bash`...

Comment: One other comment: using the `''` method generated a different error: `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Ingress.extensions "app" is invalid: spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "\"www.myhost.com\"": a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')`